# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip' error in ```cv2_imshow()```

Tags: python, opencv, keras, google-colaboratory

I was trying to create a program which could detect my face expression(from webcam).

However, while displaying my face, I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-e0549b59dd89> in <module>()
     47         print("\n\n")
     48 
---> 49     cv2_imshow(frame)
     50     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     51         break

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     20       image.
     21   """
---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     24   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

I am using Python 3.6 on Google Colab.

I am using `cv2_imshow()` from Google patches, since Colab does not support `cv2.imshow()`

Here is my code:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from keras.models import load_model
from time import sleep
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import numpy as np

face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
classifier = load_model('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/fer_68acc.h5')

class_labels = ['Angry','Happy','Neutral','Sad','Surprise']

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    labels = []
    gray = cv2.imread(frame, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        roi_gray = cv2.resize(roi_gray,(48,48),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


        if np.sum([roi_gray])!=0:
            roi = roi_gray.astype('float')/255.0
            roi = img_to_array(roi)
            roi = np.expand_dims(roi,axis=0)

        # make a prediction on the ROI, then lookup the class

            preds = classifier.predict(roi)[0]
            print("\nprediction = ",preds)
            label=class_labels[preds.argmax()]
            print("\nprediction max = ",preds.argmax())
            print("\nlabel = ",label)
            label_position = (x,y)
            cv2.putText(frame,label,label_position,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
        else:
            cv2.putText(frame,'No Face Found',(20,60),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),3)
        print("\n\n")
    
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Could someone please help?
Unfortunately, I can not run this on my local machine, so it would be helpful if someone gave a solution which can be run on Google Colab.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Does the following give you a non-zero size:

```
print(frame.shape)
```

If not, then the image is not loading properly. Nonetype means there is nothing stored in the variable called `frame`

Comment: I tried that and there is apparently nothing in the variable `frame`. I can't figure out why the webcam image isn't loading. I tried a few others' codes from Github. All of the codes give the same error.

Comment: Can you try loading and displaying an image from your webcam using code that you write on your computer? Also, I could be wrong but I don't think it is possible to let Google Colab access your webcam. I guess that would be your privacy being violated by Google servers, which is simply not allowed

Comment: I had successfully loaded the webcam image and displayed it previously on another PC. However, I don't have Python installed on this PC nor can I install it due to PC issues.

Comment: Though I remember being able to access the webcam with Colab once before.

Answer (score 1):

Use below two functions from the opencv-python package in Google colab:

1. Import `cv2` and `cv2_imshow` from `google.colab.patches` as below:

   ```py
   import cv2

   from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
   ```
2. Read image using `cv2` and display same using `cv2_imshow` as below:

   ```py
   img = cv2.imread('Folder_Name/Img.jpg')
   cv2_imshow(img)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. I wanted to detect some objects using yolov4 with my webcam. Then I found ([The AI Guy](https://www.youtube.com/c/TheAIGuy)).

He uses the code snippet for Camera Capture, which runs JavaScript code to utilize his computer's webcam. The code snippet will take a webcam photo, which he would then pass into his YOLOv4 model for object detection.

Below is a helper function to take the webcam picture using JavaScript and then run YOLOv4.

> Note:- These three single Apostrophe (''') after "js = Javascript("
> act as a comment in StackOverflow but in collab code shell it will work
> as a code.

**Taking photos by webcam:**

```
def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''       
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      capture.textContent = 'Capture';
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      // Wait for Capture to be clicked.
      await new Promise((resolve) => capture.onclick = resolve);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)

  # get photo data
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  # get OpenCV format image
  img = js_to_image(data) 
  
  # call our darknet helper on webcam image
  detections, width_ratio, height_ratio = darknet_helper(img, width, height)

  # loop through detections and draw them on webcam image
  for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
    left, top, right, bottom = bbox2points(bbox)
    left, top, right, bottom = int(left * width_ratio), int(top * height_ratio), int(right * width_ratio), int(bottom * height_ratio)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (left, top), (right, bottom), class_colors[label], 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "{} [{:.2f}]".format(label, float(confidence)),
                      (left, top - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                      class_colors[label], 2)
  # save image
  cv2.imwrite(filename, img)

  return filename
try:
  filename = take_photo('photo.jpg')
  print('Saved to {}'.format(filename))
  
  # Show the image which was just taken.
  display(Image(filename))
except Exception as err:
  # Errors will be thrown if the user does not have a webcam or if they do not
  # grant the page permission to access it.
  print(str(err))
```

Below is another helper function to start up the video stream using similar JavaScript as was used for images. The video stream frames are fed as input to YOLOv4.

```
# JavaScript to properly create our live video stream using our webcam as input
def video_stream():
  js = Javascript('''
    var video;
    var div = null;
    var stream;
    var captureCanvas;
    var imgElement;
    var labelElement;
    
    var pendingResolve = null;
    var shutdown = false;
    
    function removeDom() {
       stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
       video.remove();
       div.remove();
       video = null;
       div = null;
       stream = null;
       imgElement = null;
       captureCanvas = null;
       labelElement = null;
    }
    
    function onAnimationFrame() {
      if (!shutdown) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
      }
      if (pendingResolve) {
        var result = "";
        if (!shutdown) {
          captureCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
          result = captureCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8)
        }
        var lp = pendingResolve;
        pendingResolve = null;
        lp(result);
      }
    }
    
    async function createDom() {
      if (div !== null) {
        return stream;
      }

      div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.border = '2px solid black';
      div.style.padding = '3px';
      div.style.width = '100%';
      div.style.maxWidth = '600px';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      
      const modelOut = document.createElement('div');
      modelOut.innerHTML = "<span>Status:</span>";
      labelElement = document.createElement('span');
      labelElement.innerText = 'No data';
      labelElement.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      modelOut.appendChild(labelElement);
      div.appendChild(modelOut);
           
      video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      video.width = div.clientWidth - 6;
      video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');
      video.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
          {video: { facingMode: "environment"}});
      div.appendChild(video);

      imgElement = document.createElement('img');
      imgElement.style.position = 'absolute';
      imgElement.style.zIndex = 1;
      imgElement.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      div.appendChild(imgElement);
      
      const instruction = document.createElement('div');
      instruction.innerHTML = 
          '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">' +
          'When finished, click here or on the video to stop this demo</span>';
      div.appendChild(instruction);
      instruction.onclick = () => { shutdown = true; };
      
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      captureCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      captureCanvas.width = 640; //video.videoWidth;
      captureCanvas.height = 480; //video.videoHeight;
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onAnimationFrame);
      
      return stream;
    }
    async function stream_frame(label, imgData) {
      if (shutdown) {
        removeDom();
        shutdown = false;
        return '';
      }

      var preCreate = Date.now();
      stream = await createDom();
      
      var preShow = Date.now();
      if (label != "") {
        labelElement.innerHTML = label;
      }
            
      if (imgData != "") {
        var videoRect = video.getClientRects()[0];
        imgElement.style.top = videoRect.top + "px";
        imgElement.style.left = videoRect.left + "px";
        imgElement.style.width = videoRect.width + "px";
        imgElement.style.height = videoRect.height + "px";
        imgElement.src = imgData;
      }
      
      var preCapture = Date.now();
      var result = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        pendingResolve = resolve;
      });
      shutdown = false;
      
      return {'create': preShow - preCreate, 
              'show': preCapture - preShow, 
              'capture': Date.now() - preCapture,
              'img': result};
    }
    ''')

  display(js)
  
def video_frame(label, bbox):
  data = eval_js('stream_frame("{}", "{}")'.format(label, bbox))
  return data

# start streaming video from webcam
video_stream()
# label for video
label_html = 'Capturing...'
# initialze bounding box to empty
bbox = ''
count = 0 
while True:
    js_reply = video_frame(label_html, bbox)
    if not js_reply:
        break

    # convert JS response to OpenCV Image
    frame = js_to_image(js_reply["img"])

    # create transparent overlay for bounding box
    bbox_array = np.zeros([480,640,4], dtype=np.uint8)

    # call our darknet helper on video frame
    detections, width_ratio, height_ratio = darknet_helper(frame, width, height)

    # loop through detections and draw them on transparent overlay image
    for label, confidence, bbox in detections:
      left, top, right, bottom = bbox2points(bbox)
      left, top, right, bottom = int(left * width_ratio), int(top * height_ratio), int(right * width_ratio), int(bottom * height_ratio)
      bbox_array = cv2.rectangle(bbox_array, (left, top), (right, bottom), class_colors[label], 2)
      bbox_array = cv2.putText(bbox_array, "{} [{:.2f}]".format(label, float(confidence)),
                        (left, top - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                        class_colors[label], 2)

    bbox_array[:,:,3] = (bbox_array.max(axis = 2) > 0 ).astype(int) * 255
    # convert overlay of bbox into bytes
    bbox_bytes = bbox_to_bytes(bbox_array)
    # update bbox so next frame gets new overlay
    bbox = bbox_bytes
```

> If you don't get any benefit from the above code then please check my
> collab where I execute this code successfully.

[collab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ewUet-RQoEX3l-VcdOs0PLCYi9W7xiaa?usp=sharing)